# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-positive maxBytesPerChar

Tags: java, character-encoding

We have multithreaded java application which is doing file operation and initializing charset encoding as below.

```
Charset charset;
CharsetDecoder decoder;
CharsetEncoder encoder;
String charsetCoding = CharsetUtil.getJVMCharset();                        
charset = Charset.forName(charsetCoding);
decoder = charset.newDecoder();
encoder = charset.newEncoder();  // Exception is thrown from this line
```

We recently started to see the exception below randomly during execution, when we try to reprocess same file, it gets processed without any error, google is of no help as we couldn't find anything with similar error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-positive maxBytesPerChar
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.<init>(CharsetEncoder.java:175)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.<init>(CharsetEncoder.java:209)
    at sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1$Encoder.<init>(ISO_8859_1.java:116)
    at sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1$Encoder.<init>(ISO_8859_1.java:113)
    at sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1.newEncoder(ISO_8859_1.java:46)
    at myClass.readFile
```

Appreciate if someone can provide any help, direction in this.

I can't seem to find the full source code for jdk 5(source I have does not contain code for sun.* packages) I decompiled the Encoder class and I can't see how is this possible as code is passing hard coded value "1.0" here.

```
class ISO_8859_1$Encoder extends CharsetEncoder
{
  private final Surrogate.Parser sgp = new Surrogate.Parser();

  private ISO_8859_1$Encoder(Charset paramCharset)
  {
    super(paramCharset, 1.0F, 1.0F);
  }
```

I have the source of CharsetEncoder as below, which is getting <0 value eventhough encoder passed 1.0

```
protected CharsetEncoder(Charset cs,
             float averageBytesPerChar,
             float maxBytesPerChar)
{
this(cs,
     averageBytesPerChar, maxBytesPerChar,
     new byte[] { (byte)'?' });
}
```

"This" calls below function

```
 protected
CharsetEncoder(Charset cs,
       float averageBytesPerChar,
       float maxBytesPerChar,
       byte[] replacement)
{
this.charset = cs;
if (averageBytesPerChar <= 0.0f)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-positive "
                       + "averageBytesPerChar");
if (maxBytesPerChar <= 0.0f)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-positive "
                       + "maxBytesPerChar");***
if (!Charset.atBugLevel("1.4")) {
    if (averageBytesPerChar > maxBytesPerChar)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("averageBytesPerChar"
                       + " exceeds "
                       + "maxBytesPerChar");
```

Comment: what version of Java are you using? On mine (oracle 7), looking at the source code, I don't see how you can get that exception.

Comment: In 1.6, there is only one `Encoder` constructor and it passes a literal value of 1 to `super()` for `maxBytesPerChar`. But it's clear that you are using a different version because you have two `Encoder` constructors.

Comment: We are on JDK 1.5  Issue is that this piece of code was working fine until recently and we started to get this error randomly. I suspect it might be some change in OS configuration, but I am not able to locate what could be causing this.

Comment: @user2112430 It is unlikely to be due to the OS configuration. Possibly a concurrency bug that was fixed in later versions of Java. Can't you open the source of `sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1.Encoder` and check what it does?

Comment: @assylias I have added my comments to original post. I checked the code and this is still mysterious how the error is coming.

Comment: Just throwing the idea out there, have you tried synchronizing around the call to `charset.newEncoder()`?

Comment: @JoshDM I am not sure how that will help as maxBytesPerChar is local variable in "protected
CharsetEncoder", no other function is calling this with value <0, which could cause this variable corruption.

Comment: Well, you mentioned that it's multithreaded, but you didn't mention the scope of the first code block you posted and considering `CharsetEncoder` is not considered thread safe for Java 1.5 (see bottom of the description of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html ), I figured I'd suggest it.  Same goes for instances of `CharsetDecoder`, but I was focusing on your initial problem.

Comment: Scope of first code is per thread so there will be separate encoder object for each thread. We can try synchronizing but looking at how value of maxBytesPerChar is assigned, I am still stumped to grasp how the value is getting corrupted :(

Comment: Does the newEncoder method implement a Singleton pattern? If it's not designed for multithreading unpredictable badness may happen see for example http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html

At the end of the text at the beginning of the API, it says: "Instances of this class are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads."

Are you using a single CharsetEncoder object in multiple threads?